# YouTube send live chat message does not work

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

`youtube.liveChatMessages().insert` returns with `400` error code, reason `unexpectedPart`.

This is the same reponse received on the Google API explorer.

```
def send_message(youtube):
  send_message_response = youtube.liveChatMessages().insert (
     part = "snippet",
     body = dict (
        snippet = dict(
           liveChatId = result_chatId,
           type = "textMessageEvent",
           textMessageDetails = dict(
               messageText = "hello world"
           )
         ),
         authorDetails = dict(
             displayName = "blabla"
         )
      )
   ).execute()

   print "%s" % (send_message_response)
```

> Error response received.

[image: Error Response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the `authorDetails` resource is a dictionary returned from the API which gives details about the author of the chat message.  It is only returned from GET requests and should never be added as a parameter on a POST or PUT request, as this data can't be changed.